# A panel using FlowLayout cannot contain JScrollPanes?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, layout-manager

That's what I did at first.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500 ,300));
        setResizable(false);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        for (int i=0; i < 100; i++)
            panel.add(new JLabel("some text"));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel, 
                ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
                ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        // Here I create a JPanel to replace the contentPane of JFrame
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }
```

If instead I replace the last 3 lines with this:

```
getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
```

everything is ok. But as I did before, the vertical scrollbar is not showing up. What is causing this? Is setting a JPanel as contentPane wrong?

Update:
 If contentPane changes to BorderLayout everything work fine.

```
// Here I create a JPanel to replace the contentPane of JFrame
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
contentPane.add(scrollPane);
setContentPane(contentPane);
```

So the problem is default FlowLayout?

Solved:
 The problem is FlowLayout. It wraps around JScrollPane and hides the Toolbars. using

```
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400)); // longer space in x-axis
```

solves it.

Answer: 
JSrollPane should not be used inside a Container that uses FlowLayout.

Comment: `pack()` should be called after adding all the components, especially after `initComponents()` is called.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: For this problem specifically pack location does not matter. I tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - there is nothing bad in using your own component as content pane. But default content pane is also a JPanel instance so there is actually no point to replace it with your own panel, unless you want to use non-panel content pane or customized panel component.

This is how the default content pane looks like:

```
/**
 * Called by the constructor methods to create the default 
 * <code>contentPane</code>. 
 * By default this method creates a new <code>JComponent</code> add sets a 
 * <code>BorderLayout</code> as its <code>LayoutManager</code>.
 * @return the default <code>contentPane</code>
 */
protected Container createContentPane() {
    JComponent c = new JPanel();
    c.setName(this.getName()+".contentPane");
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout() {
        /* This BorderLayout subclass maps a null constraint to CENTER.
         * Although the reference BorderLayout also does this, some VMs
         * throw an IllegalArgumentException.
         */
        public void addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraints) {
            if (constraints == null) {
                constraints = BorderLayout.CENTER;
            }
            super.addLayoutComponent(comp, constraints);
        }
    });
    return c;
}
```

This method is taken from JRootPane. It is basically a simple JPanel with a but customized layout manager as you can see.

Now, you have a few problems in your example.

First is the order of calls - you are sizing frame before adding content into it. Simply change the order and you will see your scrollpane:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
    public MyFrame ()
    {
        super();

        // Add components first
        initComponents ();

        // Setup frame after so it fits its new content
        setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        setPreferredSize ( new Dimension ( 500, 300 ) );
        setResizable ( false );
        pack ();
        setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
    }

    private void initComponents ()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
        panel.setLayout ( new BoxLayout ( panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS ) );

        for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
        {
            panel.add ( new JLabel ( "some text" ) );
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane =
                new JScrollPane ( panel, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER );

        // Here I create a JPanel to replace the contentPane of JFrame
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel ();
        contentPane.add ( scrollPane );
        setContentPane ( contentPane );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable ()
        {
            public void run ()
            {
                new MyFrame ().setVisible ( true );
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

It will still look different because your `new JPanel ()` uses `FlowLayout` by default, instead of `BorderLayout` used by default content pane component:
[image: With FlowLayout]

Simply set `BorderLayout` and you will have the result you want to see:

```
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel ( new BorderLayout () );
```

Comment: unless I use BorderLayout. So FlowLayout is the problem?

Comment: `FlowLayout` is not a "problem" - its just a different layout that differently places components inside the container. Still, its pretty strange if the example I have shown to you didn't work with `FlowLayout` because it works for me. Make sure you tried exactly what I have posted.

Comment: I also strongly recommend you to read this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: It is pretty strange. It only works if I use BorderLayout but not with FlowLayout. I just copy pasted to a new Project and I got the same.

Comment: I have added sceenshot how the code example (with FlowLayout) looks like for me. I am using Win8.1 + JDK 1.6.0_30 just in case..

Comment: For your edit: That is what I was talking about. Why does FlowLayout affect the ScrollBar?

Comment: Because layout manager affects the way components (JScrollPane in this case) are placed within container (JPanel in this case). And this is why I said to you before that you should read this article first: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html - I am sure it will answer most of questions you have about layouts so far

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Rob Camick's [**WrapLayout**](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/), which is an extension of FlowLayout

[image][image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestWrapLayout {
    public TestWrapLayout () {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/stackoverflow2.png"));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new WrapLayout());
        for (int i = 1; i <= 250; i++) {
            JLabel iconlabel = new JLabel(icon);
            iconlabel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JLabel textlabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(i));
            textlabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            textlabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            textlabel.setFont(new Font("impact", Font.PLAIN,20));
            iconlabel.add(textlabel);
            panel.add(iconlabel);
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(panel));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new TestWrapLayout();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must update your frame after adding your panel using `pack()` function. When you do

```
getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
```

the function `add` does that for you ([ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29))

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what was the reason to create the second panel? There
is already the first panel that has `BoxLayout` as the layout
manager set. Simply setting the scroll pane having the first panel
as parent works as expected.

You either call

```
setContentPane(scrollPane);
```

or

```
add(scrollPane);
```

Now I am going to explain what caused this unexpected behaviour. This
is a quirk that sometimes happens to those who use nesting technique
when building their layouts. When nesting is used, the layouts may 
influence each other.

By choosing another layout -- `FlowLayout` -- as the underlying base layout, 
you caused the first panel to be displayed in its preferred size. Instead
of one panel, you have now two panels, the base panel influences the
panel with labels -- it controls how it is sized. The `FlowLayout` 
shows all its children in preferred size; it does not honour mimimum nor 
maximum sizes. So the (first) visible panel is sized to show all its labels;
this is how preferred size is calculated -- just big enough to show all its
children. However, with 100 labels, it is very big; the layout is broken. It is 
vertically so big that we cannot practically get to the bottom of the window.

So with our visible panel showing all its labels, what's the purpose of showing
a verticall scrollbar? No need for one, since all labels are "visible" (placed on
the window area), though the desing is broken.

So the problem does not lie with the scrollbars; they work normally. If you
set (in your example) the vertical scrollbar policy to `VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS`
you will see the scrollbar there but without a slider, since all labels are "visible" 
and there is nothing to be scrolled. (Scrollbars show items that are hidden from the
layout.) The issue lies in the fact that `FlowLayout` shows its components in the preferred size only.

The following is a fixed code example that works as expected:

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame() {

        initComponents();

        setTitle("Scrollbar");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                       
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);        

    }

    private void initComponents() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        for (int i=0; i < 100; i++)
            panel.add(new JLabel("some text"));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel, 
                ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
                ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        setContentPane(scrollPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyFrame ex = new MyFrame();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

[image: Example shapshot]